# Is there anything similar to iOS resource bundle in android?

Tags: java, android, ios

Is there anything similar to iOS resource bundle in android where we can add images,js,css files etc.

Comment: in `assets` folder you can add all things

Comment: You can check the below link .This has the solution for the above said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47217364/how-to-edit-the-assets-files-present-in-some-custom-android-libray-aar-integra