# How to edit the assets files present in some custom android libray(.aar) integrated in my project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have added an android library .aar to my android project.Now i want to edit some js, text files present in the android library assets folder not the src files.But i am not able to edit it as i have no reference to that android library assets folder.Can anyone explain how to edit the files in assets folder of android library.

Comment: If you have the library source code, you can open it as a separate project, change it, recompile it and reimport it in your project.

Comment: I want the developers who use my library to edit those files .Not me.

Comment: Then distribute the source code of your library. Or let it use external resources.

Comment: We want to give the user to edit those files from their android project.So we are checking for this option.As in iOS there is a concept of bundles where user can edit files i was checking for similar thing in android.Do u have any idea abt it.

Comment: Re-read my previous comment.

Comment: External resource means they need to add all those files in their project assets folder?

Comment: It means that you create a folder "somewhere" on the sd card (or on the internal storage). Not in the project.

Comment: No that can't be possible for the scenario which we expect.For me the user should edit those files before  building his app.

Comment: Let me know if you succeed in doing such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can go to the external libraries added to the project and check for the library and then try to open the folder from that library.

Example:-

**Steps to edit the integrated library resources(res) & assets files.**

**Step1:-**
Goto the External Libraries Section of your project in android studio and check for the your integrated library as shown in the below image. 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


**Step2:-** 
Check for the res folder in the integrated library and right click on the res folder you will get a menu.As shown in the below image. 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]


**Step3:-** 
From the displayed menu select the option “Show in Explorer”.Then the integrated library window will be opened as shown in the below image.This is the path for the assets and res folder of the integrated library. Integrated library path will be similar to Eg: C:\Users\UserName\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files1.1\integratedlibrary .aar\**************
[![enter image description here][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdhEi.png

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJgTa.png

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMjYy.png
```